# Counting letters under different columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I would like to count the number of repeated characters in excel across many columns.

I tried with Pivot Table and didn't work with me. I tried countif function but it needs more inputs and repeated the commands.

The inputs and output are,

```
**INPUT**

#Column1# a b c d
#Column2# a b s t
#Column3# b a b c


**OUTPUT**

#Column#
a=3
b=4
c=2
d=1
s=1
t=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Type this formula in some cell of column `A` of `Sheet2`, then fill with it the cells from `A` to `Z` on the same row:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$C,MID(CELL("address",A1),2,1))
```

Also possible is (using ASCII codes):

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$C, CHAR(96+COLUMN(A:A)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in range `A2:C5` and you want result to be displayed in `Column E:F`.

To get all the **unique** values from the range enter the following formula in `Cell E2`

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($A$2:$C$5<>"")*(COUNTIF(E$1:$I1,$A$2:$C$5)=0),ROW($2:$5)*100+COLUMN($A:$C),99999)),"R0C00"),)&""
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required.

Now to get the **count** of all the values in the range, in `Cell F2` enter

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$C$5,E2)
```

and drag/copy down as required. Change the range in both formulas as per your data. See image for reference.

[image]

***NOTE :*** `INDIRECT` is a volatile function. For details on volatile function see [this](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm).